# Is $U$ a connected subset of $X$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a connected topological space. Let $U$ be a dense subset of $X.$ Can we say that $U$ is also connected?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: $X=(\Bbb R, |.|)$ and $U=\Bbb Q$ disproves this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title question: yes, if $U$ is a dense subset of $X$, then $U$ is a dense subset of $X$.

Other question: no, see for instance $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.